# How to get viewbag data in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How to get viewbag data, i created one controller in that data is fetch from data base and try to show the data in view but it is not displaying data.

```
  public ActionResult Show()
    {
        List<Models.Employees> lst = new List<Models.Employees>();
        Models.Employees obj = new Models.Employees();
        DataSet ds =new Models.BL.InsertBL().GetShow(obj);
        lst = (from DataRow drw in ds.Tables[0].Rows
               select new Models.Employees
               {
                   Enames = drw["Ename"].ToString(),
                   DepartId =Convert .ToInt32(drw["Departmentid"]),
                   EmailIds = drw["Emailid"].ToString(),
                   Adress = drw["Address"].ToString()
               }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Sasi = lst; 
        return View();
    }

   @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Show";
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/VideoLayout.cshtml"; 
      var vv = ViewBag.Sasi;    
    }
```

Comment: @foreach (var lst in @vv)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                lst.Enames
            </td>
            <td>
                lst.DepartId
            </td>
            <td>
                lst.EmailIds
            </td>
            <td>
                lst.Adress
            </td>
        </tr>
     }

Comment: And whats our problem? Is ViewBag.Sasi null in your view or what happens? A better approach would be to use strongly typed views and pass the data in a model class to your view.

Comment: No jan, data is coming i put break point and check but data is shoing like lst.Ename lst.Emailids.... like that

Answer (score 3):

In this scenario I would recommend you strongly typed views:

```
return View(lst);
```

and in View:

```
@model List<Models.Employees>
```

Your question, try this:

```
(List<Models.Employees>)ViewBag.Sasi
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting strongly typed approach. viewbag and viewdata are bad choice.

Comment: yeah using strong type i got the data, but i am trying to show the data without strong type